# Angular can't find main, runtime, scripts when upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: proxy

On my project we are currently upgrading Angular from 11 to 16, one version at a time. We just finished upgrading to version 12 and everything went smooth.

But when trying to upgrade to 13 by running "ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13", the solution breaks down (on localhost). The migration itself runs without errors, but when starting up the solution (ng serve), it can no longer find main.js, runtime.js, scripts.js, etc. from index.html.

[image]

Our solution is running on a proxy being set up by Apache, so when going to /tmv in the url, it targets our angular application. This has been working fine until now by setting the  in index.html and setting the root in angular.json to "tmv". But for some reason when upgrading to Angular 13, it can't locate the application files anymore.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to create a clean angular 13 project and compare angular.json with ours. Tried all sorts of changes to the configuration, but with no luck.

Angular doesn't mention anything in breaking changes that seems relevant to this, only that base-href is deprecated, but we are not using that.

I have run out of ideas, so let me know if you have any :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was the proxy url in my apache config that was missing a /.

So where "ProxyPass /tmv http://localhost:4200/" was failing, this worked:

`ProxyPass /tmv/ http://localhost:4200/`